# Python how to generate dicts from names and reverse

Tags: python, dictionary, code-generation, generator

I want to simplify my code, especially to avoid square brackets; so my question is :

```
def someFunction():
    someString = "Hi!"
    someNumber = 22
    somePointer = ""
    someList = []

    names_list = ['someString','someNumber','somePointer','someList']
    val_list = [someString, someNumber, somePointer, someList]

    someDict = {}

    for i in range( len( names_list ) ) :
        someDict[names_list[i]] = val_list[i]  

    someOtherFunction( someDict )

def someOtherFunction( dict ):
    for key, value in dict.iteritems() :
        print key, value

    print someString, someNumber

someFunction()
```

Is it possible to make it like this?

Comment: This very unclear. What are you trying to achieve, what are somePointer, s_name and d_name?

Comment: *"especially to avoid square brackets"* I don't like where this is going, you should just use square brackets

Comment: EDITED to clarify my point. Need to generate vars where they not exists. About brackets, I used them a lot, but I don't want to use them if there's no need, that makes a code more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't get why this can be usefull
if You know list of variables and they will be used in some function

```
# generate names and values again at other place
def foo():
    for d in someDict :
        d_name = d
```

then You just can unpack them  during function call

```
def foo(someString=None,
        someNumber=None,
        somePointer=None,
        someList=None):
    pass

foo(**someDict)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you want a dict associating variable names with values. I propose that you build a list with names and a list with values. Then, you append items to your dict.

```
someString = "Hi!"
someNumber = 22
somePointer = 4
someList = []

names_list = ['someString','someNumber','somePointer','someList']
val_list = [someString, someNumber, somePointer, someList]
len_list = len(val_list)

someDict = {}

for i in range(len_list) :
    someDict[names_list[i]] = val_list[i]
```

Then, you can query your dict doing, say

```
>>> someDict['someString']
'Hi!'
```

Comment: Vote up for help. I edited my code to make it more clear that I need to generate vars in function when they do not exists.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way I found is with dict() built in constructor :

```
someString = "Hi!"
someNumber = 22
somePointer = ""
someList = []

someDict = dict( 
    string = someString, number = someNumber,
    pointer = somePointer, list = someList )

print someDict

Output : { "string" : "Hi", "number" : 22, "pointer" : "", "list" : [] }
```